# JavaScript how to prevent click before the transition ended

Tags: javascript

On click I want the background to change, but how to prevent the click until the transition is finished ?

```
var box = document.querySelector('.box');

var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var i = 0;

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    box.style.background = '' + colors[i] + '';
    console.log(colors[i]);

    i++;
    if (i == 3) {
      i = 0;
    }
});
```

The code:
http://jsbin.com/nizufi/2/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: Always include the code in the question, never just link external sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JavaScript event `transitionend`:

```js
var box = document.querySelector('.box');
var colors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
var i = 0;
var transitioning = false;

box.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if(transitioning) {
      return;
    }

    box.style.background = '' + colors[i] + '';
    console.log(colors[i]);

    i++;
    if (i == 3) {
        i = 0;
    }

    transitioning = true;
});

box.addEventListener('transitionend', function () {
  transitioning = false;
});
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks Jonny :D